# How to send keyboard outputs

Tags: java, keyboard

What can I import to simulate a keyboard press in java?

So for example I can use it to make a programme to automatically press the "a" key when an event occurs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Everything you need is in `java.awt.Robot`

Example:

```
Robot robot = new Robot(); 
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
```

Comment: Can I use this to for example, make a character fire continuously in a internet game unrelated to the java program, by using it rapidly tap a key when another key is pressed?

Comment: Yes you can. The robot simulates what happen if you really type the keyboard. The window with the focus will receive the keyboard event.