# How to start multiple jars using linux screens?

Tags: java, linux, gnu-screen

I want to start some jars in linux from Java runtime.
From the command line of Linux it would look something like this:

```
> screen -S jar1
> java -jar Something1.jar
> Ctrl + AD
> screen -S jar2
...
```

How i can do this using Java?

Comment: You cannot. However you can take a look at `screen`'s command line options, to achieve the `^AD` shortcut's functionality...

Comment: you could use the robot api to send key combination. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14595483/using-java-to-send-key-combinations) for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start a screen with its own session & command, directly detached, you can do this:

```
screen -dmS jar1 bash -c "java -jar jar1.jar"
```

That's from the command line, where `screen` will fork a new process that executes in the background so after running the above you are back in your interactive shell. But from another program you would use `-D` instead of `-d`, for example with Java you probably want the ability to `waitFor()` on the process you start.
From `man screen`:

> `-d -m`   Start screen in "detached" mode. This creates a new session but doesn't attach to it. This is useful for system startup scripts.
>       `-D -m`   This also starts screen in "detached" mode, but doesn't fork a new process. The command exits if the session terminates.

Example with 2 dummy long-running commands:

```
% screen -dmS app-top top

% screen -dmS app-foo bash -c "while sleep 1; do date; done"

% screen -ls
There are screens on:
        25377.app-foo   (08/30/2017 09:26:24 AM)        (Detached)
        24977.app-top   (08/30/2017 09:23:41 AM)        (Detached)
```

Tree of processes:

```
SCREEN -dmS app-foo bash -c while sleep 1; do date; done
 \_ bash -c while sleep 1; do date; done
    \_ sleep 1
SCREEN -dmS app-top top
 \_ top
```

So from Java, something like this:

```
private Process runInScreen(String sessionName, String command) throws IOException {
    return new ProcessBuilder("screen", "-DmS", sessionName, "bash", "-c", command).inheritIO().start();
}
```